# Unable to generate hypdoc.sty

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I am new to MikTex. Although I have learnt how to create .sty files and to install them manually, I am unable to generate the hypdoc.sty file. I downloaded the CTAN package which doesn't contain that hypdoc style file. I couldn't even get the style anywhere on the internet.

Let me explain my situation. I am trying to install MikTex to the systems of my lab where none of the systems is connected to the internet. I am just doing this manual job of copying & pasting. If someone could generate a .sty file for hypdoc, I would be grateful.

Comment: In your case I would not recommend to generate the sty files and install them manually, but use a local repository, e.g., copied to an usb drive as also explained in the answers to the duplicate question. And indeed I would recommend to use a copy of a whole repository not only a partial one. So dependencies can also be resolved.

Comment: Here is what you looking for  https://github.com/ho-tex/hypdoc download the .dtx file and just latex it to generate the .sty

Comment: Thank you all. Will check once.

Comment: @yannisl you must run `tex hypdoc.dtx` to unpack it, with `latex hypdoc.dtx` you get the documentation (that is a selfextracting dtx, the installation description is inside the dtx)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Thanks!